# Get from which IP a page was accessed via AJAX request in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simple AJAX GET request going to a certain PHP page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/remote.php",
    success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response;
    }        
});
```

The `remote.php` page echoes the `$_SERVE['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable. The response of the AJAX request is the IP address of the client itself (from which a user is navigating from).

The JS file containing the AJAX request is located on the same server, e. g. `http://example.com/js/ajaxstuff.js`.

My objective is to get from which website the PHP page was accessed from, in order to prevent users simply going on the PHP page itself to gather information. Basically, I am trying to get a result of `http://example.com` or the IP of said server when the page is accessed from AJAX, or the user's IP address if the PHP page was accessed from its browser directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a ref tag in PHP but this would not give you the correct way of getting this to work.

Option 1: Database.

A way that I would make instead would to create a mysql field with the ip and last loaded in another ajax call that would work as access control. For instance you add that into the normal page and load it with javascript for instance with setInterval() function in javascript.

When that ajax is called then the ip will be added into the table and that sets a unix timestamp.

If that timestamp is longer than 2 minutes since last load then you block your normal script for accessing. This way you can also insert a function to block ips that you know is fake or not good for your script.

Option 2: Set Session in the main php loading page.

You can create a session that you set a magic key for instance $_SESSION["access"]="YOU SECRET KEY"; and then check if this one is inside the remote.php

I would prefer the database version.

Comment: This is not exactly my goal. It's not that I want to block a certain user IP, I am trying to only allow requests that pass through the website.

Comment: Well both Option 1 and Option 2 will do that for you.

Comment: No. "The response of the AJAX request is the IP address of the client itself (from which a user is navigating from)". I want to know how the PHP page was accessed; either the user created a third-party website to get to the page via AJAX or simply connected to it via a browser, OR the page was accessed from the *only allowed JS script*, located inside the website in which the PHP file is stored too.